# May your buildings go condo

Tags: expressions

In Beetlejuice (1988) the host of the party proposes a toast

> May your buildings go condo

I don't understand this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

condo=condominium

If a building "[goes condominium](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-condominium)" it changes from having rented apartments to having owned apartments.

The construction "May (something happen)" is an expression of a wish, hope or prayer.

Comment: Wish, hope, prayer, or curse.

Comment: So it's the same as "pay off your mortgage" then?

Comment: not really the same at all. if you own a building and you "go condo" then you can kick out the rental tenants, and sell it on at a large profit.  But to go condo you need permission from the city.

Comment: I agree with the general sense of your answer ("may the building go from rental to sales") but to me it sounds like it would be a wish for the *tenants*, not the landlord.  After all, the landlord already owns the building, so it's weird to express this as something that just happens to them!  The tenant, OTOH, has less control, but may get to buy their apartment at a below-market rate.

Comment: It is ususally the other way round.  The tenants are forced to move out, since they can't afford the price of the condominium.  The building owner gets a bundle of money and new posh residents.  There is a whole social history here.